# Unable to invoke no-args constructor for retrofit2.Call

Tags: kotlin, retrofit

I have the following retrofit singleton:

```
interface MyAPI
{
    @GET("/data.json")
    suspend fun fetchData() : Call<MyResponse>

    companion object
    {
        private val BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/"

        fun create(): MyAPI
        {
            val gson = GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                .create()

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory( GsonConverterFactory.create( gson ) )
                .baseUrl( BASE_URL )
                .build()

            return retrofit.create( MyAPI::class.java )
        }
    }
}
```

MyResponse.kt

```
data class MyResponse(
    val listOfData: List<DataEntity>
)
```

DataEntity.kt

```
data class DataEntity(
    @SerializedName("name")
    val fullName: String
}
```

I call the code from ModelView the following way:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    try {
        val webResponse = MyAPI.create().fetchData().await()
        Log.d( tag, webResponse.toString() )
    }
    catch ( e : Exception )
    {
        Log.d( tag, "Exception: " + e.message )
    }
}
```

But I keep getting:

```
Unable to invoke no-args constructor for retrofit2.Call<com.host.myproject.net.response.MyResponse>. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

I can't seem to find a solution for this problem.. Any hints please?

EDIT:

The JSON response:

```
[
    {
    "name": "A"
    },
    {
    "name": "B"
    },
    {
    "name": "C"
    }
]
```

Comment: What does the JSON response look like exactly?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The problem is that you try to combine `suspend` with a `Call<T>` return type. When you use `suspend` you should make the Retrofit function return the data directly, like this:

```
suspend fun fetchData() : List<DataEntity> // Note: Not MyResponse, see below
```

Then all you have to do is to remove `.await()` when you make the call, like this:

```
// Will throw exception unless HTTP 2xx is returned
val webResponse = MyAPI.create().fetchData()
```

Note that you should not use the `MyResponse` class at all since the JSON returns an array directly.

Update:

You can also use `Response<DataEntity>` if you need the info from headers

Comment: How do you add error handling with that tho? I wanted to use `Call` since I dont have any control over errors when using the Data directly.

Comment: You error handle by catching the HttpException which is thrown by the retrofit framework for non HTTP 200-ish response codes.

Comment: removing the suspend  in the Retrofit interface

Comment: @Enselic, you are right, but if you want get some another info, you will use Call (for getting headers from server, for example)

Comment: @kirkadev you can use `Response<DataEntity>` for this case and not `Call`!

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: Remove call and handle the response

**Before:**

```
@POST("list")
    suspend fun requestList(@Body body: JsonObject): call<Profile>
```

**After**

```
@POST("list")
    suspend fun requestList(@Body body: JsonObject): Profile
```

step 2:Remove suspend and handle the response

```
 @POST("list")
     fun requestList(@Body body: JsonObject): call<Profile>
```

Comment: hello ...i used corotines in my project ...when i used suspend im getting error `unable to create call adapter for class java.lang.object` but when i remove suspend its working without error...why is it not working with supend

Answer (score 7):

I have same issue, after checking my model is fine.
Then I try to remove suspend on interface API.

```
@GET("/data.json")
suspend fun fetchData() : Call<MyResponse>
```

To be

```
@GET("/data.json")
fun fetchData() : Call<MyResponse>
```

It solved (the error Unable to invoke no-args constructor for retrofit2.Call has gone).

Comment: it's not a solution or then don't use Kotlin Coroutines at all or use it right https://stackoverflow.com/a/58430689/7767664

Answer (score 2):

In addition with @Enselic's answer,
if you want to get response (for error handling etc.) you can return **Response<T>** class of Retrofit2 instead of returning data directly.
For example,

```
@POST("/api/news")
@CheckResult
suspend fun getNewsList(
    @Body newsRequest: NewsRequest
): Response<NewsResponse>
```

Comment: or `try...catch` and get it from `HttpException`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using suspend fuction, just remove it

```
  @GET("v1/clients/{client_id}/promocode-info/")
    suspend fun getPromoCodeInfo(
        @Path("client_id") clientId: String,
        @Query("promocode") promoCodeName: String,
    ): PromoCodeResponse


    @GET("v1/clients/{client_id}/promocode-info/")
    fun getPromoCodeInfo(
        @Path("client_id") clientId: String,
        @Query("promocode") promoCodeName: String,
    ): PromoCodeResponse
```