# Confusion about the use of Call<> and suspended functions in Android network requests with retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

After searching for answers to an error where my function *fun getRestaurants(): Call* couldn't be made suspended, I found [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58429501/unable-to-invoke-no-args-constructor-for-retrofit2-call) that you can't combine a suspended function with a Call<> return, and my problem was solved. However, I still don't fully understand when to use Call<> and when to suspend the function, at least in this context where I am making @GET and @POST requests to the API, as I understand there is an input and output of data, so it is better to work with a suspended function, but then what is the purpose of Call in this situation.

```
interface RestaurantsApiService {
@GET("restaurants?populate=*")
fun getRestaurants(): Call<Restaurants>
}
```

or

```
interface RestaurantsApiService {
@GET("restaurants?populate=*")
suspend fun getRestaurants(): Restaurants
}
```

Currently, in my application, I am using Call because the book I am learning from does, and although it later changes Call to a suspended function, it doesn't really explain why or what the benefit of doing so is.

I know and understand why to use and how to handle coroutines, which I can do when I call *getRestaurants()* inside another function/val etc, but my doubt is precisely at *getRestaurants()*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call is for when you’re not using coroutines at all. Mostly it would be used in pure Java projects. It doesn’t make sense to use it if you’re using coroutines unless you’re working on a legacy project where there are some modules not using coroutines yet. Then you can use Call and inside a coroutine you would call `await()` on it to get the result in a suspending, synchronous way.

Comment: and which method should I call?

Comment: @SebastianCorradi, I’m not sure I understand your question. You can either define your function to return a `Call<YourThing>` or you can define it as a suspend function that directly returns `YourThing`. If you’re using Kotlin, define it as a suspend function.

Comment: ok, o figured out, I should call execute and catch http Exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You can even use `Call` with `coroutines`. Use `getRestaurants().execute()`. This is a blocking call. So, you can use it inside a coroutine scope.

```kotlin
fun callInsideCoroutine() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    val result = restaurantsApiService.getRestaurants().execute()
}
```

Since, you can't directly put the whole `callInsideCoroutine()` method inside `try...catch` block, use this extension method to handle exceptions:

```kotlin
fun <T> Call<T>.execute(onError: ((e: Exception) -> Unit)? = null): Response<T>? {
    return try {
        execute()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        onError?.invoke(e)
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect use of `CoroutineScope`. See first paragraph of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75722985/using-emptycoroutinecontext-to-getstrng-from-sharedpreferences/75727334#75727334  You can just use suspending `await()` instead of blocking `execute()` if you're in a coroutine so you don't have to specify Dispatchers.IO.

Comment: I know. It should be `lifecycleScope`. But for simplicity, I didn't mention here. `await()` will also block the coroutine, won't it? Secondly, to use `await` I should launch a `coroutine`, shouldn't I? Plus, I put the `Dispatcher.IO` to avoid `network on main thread exception`. BTW, thanks for correcting me.

Comment: That `CoroutineScope(...).launch` antipattern is used like crazy by newbies. Best not to use it in an example because you're reinforcing the anti-pattern for learners who see your answer. `await` is suspending so it doesn't block. Since it is available, there's no reason to use `execute()` on the IO dispatcher like in your first code block above. When you call a suspend function, you don't have to specify the dispatcher, because suspend functions don't block (unless you composed it yourself and incorrectly called blocking code in it without using an appropriate dispatcher).